# Alone in Bronson Canyon

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, geometry

[image: Alone in Bronson Canyon]

Clues: [contextual images]

[boat shape made of more shapes, each with letters inside]
[box within a box]
[arms on either side]
[water]

Instructions: Name That Captain

_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ A _ _

Hint #1:

> [image: Hint]

Hint #2:

> [image: Hint 2]

Comment: (Please excuse any inproper wording - english is not my native language.)

Hm. I am (more than strongly) thinking of a captin, which name would fit. In that context also title and these two limbs make sense to me. Somehow even the ship and water. But I am lost with letters, box(es) and the geometry tag.

(rot13  Be zvtug vg or gung jr ner vaqrrq ybbxvat sbe n "serapu" punc naq V fubhyq tvir vg n gel?)

Comment: [[1]] Are the Shapes having the correct Size ? Particularly : Should the box within the box be larger ? [[2]] Is this related to "Gbz Glyre Pncgnva Zneiry" ??

Comment: All of the shapes are the correct sizes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I have to give it a try - since the additional hints somehow confirm my first intention:

> Bronson canyon is famous for many movies and series that are shot there, so I started wondering if we are searching a fictive character from the big/not so big screen. And began checking with my (nerdy) favorites. Thus, of course includes star trek.

> So, what remarkable episodes are out there? (Considering the title, a robinsonade would be great) For TNG that's (imho) S05E02 - "Darmok".  And since our bald hero is somehow stranded on a planet with a guy (Dathon) that repeadly tells him "Temba, his **arms wide**"...

But what about the hints?..

> Well, after fiddling the other pieces into the square, the outer letters read a reassuring word/name:
>  [image: confirmed]

With all that in mind, I suppose that famous captain is...

> JeanLucPicard

OP Edit:

> Additionally, the Darmok square is on water, referring to the line from S05E02 "Darmok on the ocean". "Darmok on the ocean" is a metaphor for loneliness or isolation, thus, the rest of the hint in the title.

Comment: Nice One , though when I tried putting those Pieces on the Square , it was a little too small , hence my Query to OP !